# jface tableviewer, how to use different cell editor for each cell?

Tags: jface, tablecelleditor, tableviewer

is there a way to specify different cell editor for each cell in jface tableviewer, I know that the cell editor is specified on a column basis, but I want to specify the cell editor on a cell basis, is there a workaround or is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`EditingSupport`](https://www.eclipse.org/documentation/) that you set to [`ViewerColumn`](https://www.eclipse.org/documentation/) is dynamic. When cell edit is triggered, the framework calls `CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element)` method on your editing support implementation. In that method you can choose to return any editor depending on the passed row *element*.